# gdb gives an error, but program runs fine

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

I have a simple C program which has a pointer to a character array. To initiate it, I use `malloc`, and resize then set it x number of times later on in the program.

When I resize it once with `realloc`, **gdb** doesn't show any errors, however, if I try calling the resize function again, **gdb** shows the following error:

```
warning: Invalid Address specified to RtlReAllocateHeap( 003E0000, 00404076 )
```

Any ideas why resizing it more than once gives this error?

**EDIT**

I played around with it and it seems the error doesn't happen when I comment out the setting of the pointer data, which is after the resizing.

```
void setName(struct class_x *class, char *name)
{
    class->name = (char *) reallocateMemory(class->name, sizeof(char) * strlen(name) + 1);
    class->name = name;
}

void *reallocateMemory(void *member, size_t size)
{
    void *tmp = realloc(member, size);
    if(tmp == NULL)
    {
        //handle
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

Comment: What does the code calling realloc look like?

Comment: Are you checking for failure after the realloc ?

Comment: It's no error it is a warning

Comment: I think you have an error on line 42. Or, show us some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`class->name = name` isn't doing what you think it is.  Use `strncpy()` to copy the input string into your newly allocated memory.  That assignment you have there is leaking your allocated memory and overwriting the pointer.  Then the next time you call `setName()`, you end up calling `realloc()` with a pointer that you didn't get from `malloc()`.  I expect somewhere that you're calling `setName()` with a constant, global variable, or local variable string, and that's what eventually generates the error.  If you were only ever calling `setName()` with strings whose memory you got from `malloc()`, you wouldn't see the warning from gdb (but you'd still have the bug!).

Comment: And given that you're always overwriting what was stored in the allocated buffer, there's no need to use `realloc` at all - just `free` and `malloc` will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

run it under valgrind or electric fence - these will spot memory overruns for you